# Why does $c$ in mean value theorem converge to $a$ and $b$, where $a < c < b$?

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives

In the context of proving integral rule ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#/search)), I'm very confused to why the following statement is true:

> A form of the mean value theorem, $\int_a^b f(x)dx = (b-a)f(\xi)$
>    where $a < \xi < b$, may be applied to the first and last integrals of
>    the fomula for $\Delta \psi$ above, resulting in $$ \Delta \psi =
>  -\Delta a f(\xi_1, \alpha + \Delta \alpha) + \int_a^b [f(x,\alpha + \Delta \alpha) - f(x,\alpha)] dx + \Delta b f(\xi_2, \alpha + \Delta
>  \alpha)$$ Divide by $\Delta \alpha$ and let $\Delta \alpha \to 0$. Notice $\xi_1
>  \to a$ and $\xi_2 \to b$.

It's the last part that is puzzling. Why do $\xi_1 \to a$ and $\xi_2 \to b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\xi_1$ is from the interval $(a,a+\Delta a)$ corresponding to an integral $\int_a^{a+\Delta a}$.
The mean value theorem is only applied on this small interval, not on $(a,b)$.
As $\Delta a\to0$, this interval shrinks and therefore $\xi_1\to a$.
Similarly, $\xi_2\in(b,b+\Delta b)$.

It might be that $\Delta a$ or $\Delta b$ is negative, but the proof works in that case as well with suitable reinterpretation.

In the calculation both $a$ and $b$ depend on $\alpha$ in a differentiable way.
The calculation (which is insufficiently explained in Wikipedia) we have $\Delta a=a(\alpha+\Delta\alpha)-a(\alpha)$.
Therefore $\Delta a\to0$ as $\Delta\alpha\to0$ and similarly for $b$.

Comment: sorry, i made a typo, it's $\alpha \to 0$ not $a \to 0$. If $\Delta \alpha$ goes to 0, how do we get $\xi_1 \to a$?

Comment: @MoneyBall I expanded my answer. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: It makes sense to say that $\xi_1 \to a$ and $\xi_2 \to b$ before using mean value theorem. after using mean value theorem, i get something like $-(a(\alpha + \Delta \alpha) - a(\alpha)) f(\xi_1, \alpha + \Delta \alpha) + (b(\alpha + \Delta \alpha) - b(\alpha))f(\xi_2, \alpha + \Delta \alpha)$. But I don't see how setting $\Delta \alpha \to 0$ makes $\xi_1 \to a$ and $\xi_2 \to b$ after using mean value theorem.

Comment: @MoneyBall Because $\xi_1\in(a,a+\Delta a)$, corresponding to an integral over this interval. The mean value theorem is only applied to the integral of length $|\Delta a|$, not to the whole interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: ah i see. since this mean value theorem is only applied between $\alpha$ to $\alpha + \Delta \alpha$, as $\Delta \alpha$ goes to 0, $\xi_1$ will go to $a$. Thank you!